# Java min max 0 to terminate

Tags: java

I am letting the user define the amount of integers he is going to compare and print min and max. but if one of the integers  entered is 0 the programs needs to terminate, print the max and min of whatever numbers have been entered til then.I cant figure out how to terminate the program if the user inputs a 0. Any help is appreciated.

```
package lu.ics.Sohail.labbar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ovningsuppgift323 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input2= new Scanner(System.in);
                 int number;
                 int max = 0;
                 int min = 0;
                 int antal;

                 System.out.println("Amount of input numbers");
                 antal = input2.nextInt();



                       for (int x = 0; x<antal; x++){ 
                             System.out.print("Give me an integer: "); 
                             number = input.nextInt(); 





                             if (x == 0 || number > max){ 
                                 max = number;  
                             }               
                             if (x == 0 || number < min){ 
                                 min = number;  
                             }               
                       }



                       System.out.println("Highest value: " + max);
                       System.out.println("Lowest value: " + min);        


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just break the loop :

```
for (int x = 0; x<antal; x++){ 
        System.out.print("Give me an integer: "); 
        number = input.nextInt(); 

        if(number == 0) break;

         /***/
}
```

More about [branching statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Comment: Exactly. I'd also like to point out to the OP that if you have a means to break from the loop (I'd use "empty line" rather than zero, since zero could be valid input), you may not need to ask how numbers will be input beforehand.